# Why youtube video is not loading inside iframe using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I am trying to get Json data from a link and I am getting all the data but youtube link is not getting loaded inside iframe. where did I commit mistake? Pls help.

```
  $.each(data,function(index,item){
    content +='<div class="userdata">';
    content +='<div class="username">'+item.bloopid+'</div>';
    content +='<div class="username">'+item.bombscount+'</div>';
    content +='<div class="userurl">'+item.keywords+'</div>';
      content +='<iframe class="usevideourl" src="'+item.videourl+'"></iframe>';
     content += '<img src="'+item.thumb+'" class="userimage"></img>';
    content +='</div>';
  })
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the iframe url to the embed video. http://jsfiddle.net/f7cRj/4/

```
$.each(data,function(index,item){
  content +='<div class="userdata">';
  content +='<div class="username">'+item.bloopid+'</div>';
  content +='<div class="username">'+item.bombscount+'</div>';
  content +='<div class="userurl">'+item.keywords+'</div>';
  content +='<iframe class="usevideourl" src="'+item.videourl.replace('watch?v=','embed/')+'"></iframe>';
  content += '<img src="'+item.thumb+'" class="userimage"></img>';
  content +='</div>';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reconstruct the source:

```
var src = item.videourl.replace("/watch?v=","/embed/");
```

### --DEMO--